# How to use LyX to produce STOP (Sequential Thematic Organization of Publications) documents

Tags: lyx

I want to produce documents in the STOP format (Sequential Thematic Organization of Publications). STOP was pioneered by the Hughes Aircraft Company in the Sixties and is regarded as a forerunner of DITA and other modular topic-based formats.

STOP documents are presented as two-page spreads, and have a prominent thesis sentence under the title of each module. The two-page spreads are called "storyboards".

The STOP Report is here, and is itself in the STOP format:

https://github.com/johngtait/ditabook/blob/master/STOP_Original%20Report.pdf

The book "The Joy of X: An Overview of the X Window System" by Niall Mansfield was written (many moons ago) in LaTeX and follows the STOP format.

I want to use LyX to produce STOP documents. (I could use LaTeX if I don't need to be an expert to set it up.) What is the best way?

Comment: This sounds related to one of LyX's Google Summer of Code projects. See here: http://wiki.lyx.org/Devel/SummerOfCode2013Ideas#toc5

Comment: I'm really not sure what exactly a good answer here would be! Please clarify the question.